# NodeJS promisified glob: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-promisify

Basically, this error suddenly appeared after I updated all my NPM dependencies in the project and this affected the situation (likely particularly `glob` or `typescript`).

The fragment of code below comes from a program, used in a Discord.js bot for importing and registering commands for file paths.

```
import { glob } from 'glob';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const globPromise = promisify(glob);

const slashCommandFiles = await globPromise(
      `${__dirname}/../Commands/Slash/*/*{.ts,.js}`
);

slashCommandFiles.forEach(async (filePath) => {
      const command: CommandType = await this.importFile(filePath);
      if (!command.name) return;

      this.commands.set(command.name, command);
      commands.push(command);
});
```

Error message:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
util.d.ts(1054, 141): An argument for 'arg2' was not provided.
```

I still cannot figure out what kind of a second argument...

Node version: 19.6.0

Dependencies:
"glob": "^10.1.0",
"@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
"@types/node": "^18.15.11",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
"typescript": "^5.0.4"

Comment: how are you constructing `globPromise`?

Comment: @DanielA.White, sorry, forgot to put that, edited now.

Comment: glob 10 seems to already have types as well as a promise based interface - I'd simplify your usage

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel A. White mentioned, glob 10 allows avoiding using `promisify` now. I can simply call the `glob()` function with the path passed as if I was calling `globPromisify`.